# Mouse Leaving the Game Window

Tags: pc, star-wars-kotor-2

With the recent patch from the Aspyr team for KOTOR 2, the game has become playable again with full support for higher resolutions and mods. This is fantastic, and I'm very happy to be playing again!

There is one slight problem though. The game allows you to move the camera left or right by moving the mouse to the left or right edges of the screen. I have a dual monitor set-up, and when I move the mouse to the right, it simply jumps out of the game and doesn't move the camera.

This is not a huge issue, as holding right-mouse button allows for greater free look. But sometimes I try to move the camera to the right, and I always catch myself wondering why it didn't turn.

Is there a fix/an external program to lock the mouse to the game?

Comment: Is the game in full screen or a borderless window?

Comment: As far as I know, it's true full screen.